# I want to make HTML links open a js accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I want the HTML links in the top hat to open the js accordion in the main content area to the correct location. e.g., I want the "About" link to open up the "chirp..." section.

http://imip.rvadv.com/index2.html

I don't know alot of js, so please explain carefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set and id to the "about me" link like so :

```
<a href="#aboutme" id="aboutme">
```

You should also add an id to the link element that opens the "chirp" section :

```
<a href="#" id="chirp">Chirp. Would you like to know about me?<h2>Read the official birdwatcher's guide.</h2></a>
```

Then make use of the [jQuery.click() event](http://api.jquery.com/click/). As it is explained in jQuery's documentation :

> "Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event,
>   or trigger that event on an element."

Example :

```
$("#other").click(function() {
  $("#target").click();
});
```

Applied to your page :

```
$("#aboutme").click(function() {
  $("#chirp").click();
});
```

Do not forget to wrap the JS code with "script" tags :

```
<script>
$("#aboutme").click(function() {
  $("#chirp").click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Tiffani Hollis : Now put that JS outside of the noscript tags :-)

Comment: You rock! Worked perfectly. Thanks!